# warning Undefined: No Authorization header detected

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[Undefined Warnings image Click here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gOyc.png)

I am getting this undefined warning. Anyone had encounter same? i do not have clue where does this coming from. If I click on it, I am redirected to .csproj file. Please tell me if anyone have solution.

I tried to find it on internet nothing helpful I found yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you can't get your nuget packages. Sorry but it's not enough information to tell you what else could be wrong.

Comment: @Jivopis May be possible. These warnings seen after i updated my project from .
NET 7 to .NET 8. But i updated all nuget package to version 8 yet no luck. Can you tell me any other way i can do anything. Thanks.

Comment: Try to clean your solution and rebuild it again, then check ```Output``` log.

Comment: @Jivopis did so many time. Also undo changes form source control re updated NuGet again. still not helpful. Only count decreased by 2 warnings. No more updates in NuGet.

Thanks for the help thpugh.

Comment: did you go through the Output log? Do you see anything interesting there?

Comment: @Jivopis Already done.

Comment: If this issue occurs because you are using .net 8.0, you can try to check whether the csproj file of the file has been correctly switched to .net 8.0. In addition, if you use token authorization, you need to re-authorize when switching to .net 8.0 version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: @WenbinGeng Seems like this one is the solution, My project uses token authorization for a custom NuGet pkg. as i am the new developer in this firm and previous developer left (No documentation for set ups!!!) no one have idea about it. But Thanks, Problem solved. really Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this issue occurs because you are using .net 8.0, you can try to check whether the csproj file of the file has been correctly switched to .net 8.0. In addition, if you use token authorization, you need to re-authorize when switching to .net 8.0 version